# deploy ASP.net 4.5 IBM cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud

net 4.5  Application developed with SQL server as a Back end. Can I host my applicaion in IBM cloud. As a part of customer requirement, I need to host it into IBM cloud.d.

Comment: Yes, you can host both your app and SQL Server in IBM Cloud. What have you tried and what problem are you experiencing?

Comment: How can I host a ASP.net 4.5 application without IIS?.Does IBM bluemix have IIS server support?

Comment: StackOverflow does not teach programming or application development. If you have a programming question, post your code and error messages. Then we can help you. Note: Bluemix means different things. If you mean IBM Cloud, then you can deploy a Windows Server with IIS and host ASP.NET.

Comment: thank you. I will try it out